# System Bar hides menu items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-3.0-honeycomb

We developed an android app for version 2.1 but the customers requires it should be working on 3.0 too. Everything seems fine but I have a problem with the system bar. It hides the menu buttons as https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXkzL.png

What can I do about it?

Thanks in advance. 
edit: here is the layout file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/imageandsoundroot"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/imageandsoundcontextmenutrigger"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imageandsoundimage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I was using too large images for the menu items. I used smaller images and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, this will not happen. The only way I can think of to make it happen would be to do what developers are repeatedly told *not to do*, which is try sizing things based upon physical screen size (e.g., via `DisplayMetrics`).

Fix your code to use traditional approaches for sizing (e.g., `android:layout_height="match_parent"`), and I suspect that this problem will go away.

Comment: I am using Sdk version 7 and match_parent introduced at Sdk version 8. I am not using DisplayMetrics to resize the screen. I am posting the xml file to the question